# How could Avada Kedavra have not killed George Weasley if it hit his ear?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

In the Harry Potter books, George Weasley is hit with the killing curse in the ear. His ear is blown off but he is fine. How is this possible? It hit him but didn't kill him. How does that work?

Comment: The Weasleys are all born with sentient ears. The ear was a second person, and did not survive the attack.

Comment: @JohnO And [they've been spawning](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Extendable_Ears)!  (o_0)

Comment: @JohnO - the ears are actually the only remnant of a conjoined twin

Answer (score 39):

He was not hit by the killing curse. He was accidentally hit by Sectumsempra, by Snape who was aiming for another Death Eater.

> Now Harry was flying alongside Snape on a broomstick
>   through a clear dark night: he was accompanied by other hooded
>   Death Eaters, and ahead were Lupin and a Harry who was really
>   George ... a Death Eater moved ahead of Snape and raised his
>   wand, pointing it directly at Lupin’s back –
>   ‘*Sectumsempra*!’ shouted Snape.
>   But the spell, intended for the Death Eater’s wand hand, missed
>   and hit George instead –
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 552 - Bloomsbury - *The Prince's Tale*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[Slytherincess's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/36588/100430) is correct, but the quote contained therein doesn't explicitly state that it was the Sectumsempra that cut off George's ear. There is, however, a different quote which makes it more explicit. Back in the beginning of *Deathly Hallows* we have the following conversation:

> Where's George?
>
> "He's lost an ear," said Lupin.
>
> "Lost an — ?" repeated Hrmione in a high voice.
>
> "Snape's work," said Lupin.
>
> *"Snape?"* shouted Harry. "You didn't say —"
>
> "He lost his hood during the chase. Sectumsempra was always a specialty of Snape's.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't the killing curse he was hit by. It was sectumsempra.